# Make floating list elements equal height (with pure css)

Tags: html, css, height, html-lists, css-float

I have a list of lists. Sublists are floated left. See http://jsfiddle.net/P4Psf/

Is there a way to force these columns to be the same height as their neighbors (i.e. have Element 1, 2 and 3 equal height, then 4, 5, 6 equal height (but of course different from 1,2,3) etc. etc.)?

At the moment 7 and 8 put themselves below 5 and 6, where they actually should be below 4 and 5.

I of course could do this using javascript, but I'm hoping that there is a pure CSS solution that works in (at least) the modern browsers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
ul.themenboxen > li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

That will literally search in this form:

1. Find all elements which match `:nth-child(3n+1)`, meaning every third element inside its parent.
2. Filter only those who are `li`s.
3. Filter only those who are direct descendants of `ul.themenboxen`.

Or in english, **find every third element directly inside of `ul.themenboxen`**, and apply `clear: both` on it.

*Note:* I'm not sure about lower IE support.

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/P4Psf/1/)

Comment: You, Sir, are a scholar, and a gentleman! I'll give you the correct answer, as soon as Stackoverflow allows me to (since when do we have to wait to do this?)

Comment: Dunno, I noticed it too. NP by the way :)

Comment: I don't fully understand what this is doing yet, but it's doing exactly what I want it to! I changed it to be 4 columns.

Comment: @NinjaBomb: Well, it will search `ul.themenboxen` for all **direct children** which are `li`s, and fit in the formula `3n+1`, meaning the 1st (n=0), 4th (n=1), 7th (n=2), and so on.

Comment: Friggin' magic. Best if you just say `li:nth-child(kn+1)` where `k` equals the number of columns per row.