# Order data in three columns instead of one

Tags: php, row

At the moment, with the code from below, I have the data shown like this:

http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/8083/29769986.jpg

but I want it to be shown like this:

http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/3233/24033830.jpg

The code for the data shown, as it is on the first image, is:

```
<div id="content">
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
  <div class="manufacturer-list">
    <div class="manufacturer-heading"><?php echo $category['name']; ?><a id="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>"></a></div>
    <div class="manufacturer-content">
      <?php if ($category['manufacturer']) { ?>
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['manufacturer']);) { ?>
      <ul>
        <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['manufacturer']) / 4); ?>
        <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
        <?php if (isset($category['manufacturer'][$i])) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['manufacturer'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['manufacturer'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I order to get the "Hewlett-Packard" text under the "HTC" text, I've changed the "/ 4" into "/ 1", but I have no idea how to make the data to be shown into three columns (like on the second picture), instead of one, as it is now (as shown on the first picture).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** What I actually need, is to count and to do the calculation on this code:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
.
.
.
<?php } ?>
```

So it needs to count the number of categoris, do the calculations, and present the code between into three columns.

Comment: See my answer to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204565/make-floating-list-elements-equal-height-with-pure-css/7204616#7204616

Comment: Please show us the raw HTML output of your code, without the `<?php ?>` blocks. The best way is to load the page and copy paste its source from "view source".

Comment: I just make an EDIT, so it would be simpler, I think, so can you please see the EDIT part...

Comment: See my answer for a reviewed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<div id="content">
<div class="content-column">
  <?php 
    $cols = 3; // Change to columns needed.
    $catcount = count($categories);
    $catpercol = ceil($catcount / $cols);
    $c = 0;
    foreach ($categories as $category) { 
      if ( $c == $catpercol ) {
        $c = 0;
        print "</div><div class='content-column'>";
      }
 ?>
  <div class="manufacturer-list">
    <div class="manufacturer-heading"><?php echo $category['name']; ?><a id="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>"></a></div>
    <div class="manufacturer-content">
      <?php if ($category['manufacturer']) { ?>
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['manufacturer']);) { ?>
      <ul>
        <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['manufacturer']) / 4); ?>
        <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
        <?php if (isset($category['manufacturer'][$i])) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $category['manufacturer'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['manufacturer'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php $c++; } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Add `.content-column { float: left; width: 33.33333%; }` to your CSS.

Details: 
`$cols = 3;` enables you to set the desired number of columns (note: you might need to change CSS accordingly).

`$catcount = count($categories);` gives you the total number of categories about to be rendered.

`$catpercol = ceil($catcount / $cols);` divides that total number evenly into the required number of columns with the last column having eventually less items than the others.

`$c = 0;` is your counter. It increases at the end of the outer foreach loop.

Within the loop, `$c`is checked if it matches the `$catpercol` number and if so, the current parent div is closed and a new one created. You end up with as many parent divs as you need columns. Just add appropiate CSS to make them appear besides each other.

Comment: Did you add the CSS? The code actually separates the `.manufacturer-list`s divs into parent divs (`.content-column`). These parent divs are then floated with a width of 33%. Works fine for me.

Comment: Ok, now it's working :) But it makes the order one next to another, not under it, like A, than B under A, C under B, etc. Now it's A, next to it B, next to it C, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just CSS that needs to be edited. Do you have an example link?

Comment: Yeap, now should be fine :) Let me just test the code for a while, and I think we have a winner ;)

Comment: P.S. Can you please also add the previous code, if it's not to much troube, where they were arranged next to each other? I might go with that one, I'll see, want to have it just in case ;) Thanks.

Comment: My code actually wasn't supposed to show them in a row. If you need to have it that way, you don't need to alter the PHP code at all and go with MireSVK's solution. Just add the CSS to `.manufacturer-list`.

Comment: Any ideas what and where should I add text-width to be 100% ? Now, it squizes the text within each column (I think this 33.33333% affects the columns inside as well), it's not from one end to another per column... Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell without an example link where we could take a look. Could be good range of things to cause that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YLnNW/ Notice the "Hewlett-Packard" how it's squized in two lines, and it should be in one line.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/YLnNW/1/  -- Just add white-space:nowrap; to your `<a>` tags.

Comment: Ok, take that white-space out again, the problem is `.manufacturer-list ul { width: 25%; }`. Get rid of that line and it works.

Comment: And we have a winner :) Thank you so much buddy, really appreciate it ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to create three column layout via html/css and without any change of your PHP code. Just use `float:left; width: 33%`. You can also use absolute value for width property because of margins and borders.

Comment: Adding float:left to .manufacturer-list would put "C" right to "A" and not below it.

Answer (score 0):

understand the following code that according to your requirement, the code just give the hint to achieve that you want according to your given screen shoot  http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/3233/24033830.jpg

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

$i = 1;

do{

  // column range
  $range = 3;

  echo "<td>" . $i;

  if( $i % $range == 0 ){
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  }

  echo "</td>";

  $i++;

}while( $i <= 10 );

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Just as MireSVK's answer this would put A,C,H into one row and not in a column.

Comment: I just edited the question, so if you can take a look at the EDIT part :) Thanks.

Comment: @Paul i just give an example to show the data in the column with php, thats why i used table, the same approach will be apply on the `div` but need some css as well